# Class member is not initialized in derived class using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to define some fields of derived class in declarative way, like this (consider this is minimal code example):

```
abstract class Car {
  model: string;

  constructor() {
    // some initializing
    console.log(`Car model: ${this.model}`);
  }
}

class Dodge extends Car {
  model = 'Dodge';

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

const dodge = new Dodge();
```

The problem is that `model` seems to be not initialized yet when I try to access it from constructor, so I get:

`Car model: undefined`

How to do it in a correct way?

Comment: Hope the duplicate answers your question, if not let me know.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir scarcely. Consider you have to do a lot of work in constructor of base class with attributes defined in childs. Following DRY principle it's more convenient to just declare member in derived class without duplicating same code in methods like init.

Comment: I agree it would be useful but you would run into problems either way you initialize the fields (ie before or after the base contrsuctor) The ES spec chose one version (and most languages use this version too, derived class fields are initialized after the base class constructor )